# update_attributes() vs. update_all () & on deleted object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes

I'm trying to update the attributes of an Object, but often the Object i try to update doesn't exist anymore.

E.g.: I'm post-processing a CSV file to get the attributes:

```
array.each do |a|
  player = Player.find_by_grepo_id(a[:grepo_id])
  player.update_attributes(a)
end
```

That will throw an error when a Player is not found.

What i learned from previous experiences:

> ActiveRecord::Base.find always throws an exception if it does not find a record, this is intentional. 
>   I should only use find if I'm absolutely expect to have whatever it is I'm looking for. 
>   If I'm rending a show action and can't find the article, I should rescue that exception and render a 404 (Not found) 
>   instead of redirecting to index (technically).
>
> If I want to find something by it's id attribute without forcing an exception, I should use the dynamic finder 
>   find_by_id (In my case find_by_grepo_id) which will return false if it doesn't find a record with that id.

But upon running the task which contains the above code i get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass
```

That's because a Player with that specific id doesn't exist anymore. If i wrap the `update_attributes` call in a `.present?` method it works.

What am i missing? Shouldn't the find_by_id method NOT throw an error and just skip it ?

Comment: It's throwing an error when you're attempting to update, not on the find.  So it's not throwing an error on `Player.find_by_grepo_id(a[:grepo_id])`

Comment: Your error is clearing telling, what's the mess.. Read the error again.

Comment: Is there a similar way for the update call or do i have to wrap it in a .present? method?

Comment: You can do also `execute("update table_name set col_name1=expr1, col_name2=expr2 where grepo_id = a[:grepo_id]` (syntax is MySQL, you can use your DB)

Comment: That sounds quick :) I will test it out, Thanks Arup

Comment: @ArupRakshit why use `execute` if you can use the [`update_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all) method...

Comment: @Mischa Just to do the task, in a single database scan.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yeah, that's what `update_all` does too. It results in exactly the same SQL as your `execute`. I think it's better to use what ActiveRecord provides, if possible. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in one call instead of two, you can use the [`update_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all) method like this:

```
Player.where(:grepo_id => a[:grepo_id]).update_all(a)
```

This will result in the following SQL:

```
UPDATE players SET ... = ..., ... = ... WHERE players.grepo_id = ...
```

Also works if the `grepo_id` doesn't exist: nothing will get updated. Note however that this just runs the SQL; **any validations or callbacks on your model are ignored**.

Comment: Humm.. Good to learn. I'm very new to rails. I thought like your answer, but besides thought also, it will first scan the DB(using `where`, one query), then will perform the *update* (another query)..

Comment: CC: @ArupRakshit: Ok, i'm confused. Shouldn't be the 1 Call Method be quicker then the 2 Call Method? When using the code in the accepted answer i get a completed Time = 0.52 Minutes (ca. 30 Seconds), Now i tried the 1 call method and it still running 5 Minutes in.. Am i missing something ?

Comment: @TheMiniJohn The mine one is taking *5 mins* ??? :) How ? Did you make it properly, be careful, otherwise some wrong DB update would happen.

Comment: :P Would be cool if you guys could join me for a quick Chat => http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52754/update-attributes-vs-update-all

Comment: The problem I see with this answer is that the update does not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations. Depending on the model this might lead to invalid data. I think you should prefer @BachanSmruty answer, even when it is a bit slower.

Comment: @spickermann, that's a valid point. I should have mentioned that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to you are doing update_attributes even if it does not find the record by grepo_id. find_by_grepo_id returns nil if it does not find any record. So you need to add a condition to get rid of this error.

```
array.each do |a|
  player = Player.find_by_grepo_id(a[:grepo_id])
  player.update_attributes(a) if player.present?
end
```

Comment: That's basically where i'm right now :) But isn't that bad Practice? It makes 3 calls to the DB. (Tell me if i'm wrong)

Comment: 3 calls why.. The code will do 2 calls. one is to find the record, second one is to update_attributes. `player.present?` does not call db. It just checks if it is nil then return false it has some value, it will return true.

Comment: Ok that's what i wanted to know :) Thanks Bachan

Answer (score 0):

Rails has a `try` method ([check the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try)) and you can use it here:

```
array.each do |a|
  player = Player.find_by_grepo_id(a[:grepo_id])
  player.try do |p|
   p.update_attributes(a)
  end
end
```

This should work fine and updating attribute or silently failing (without throwing exceptions) when no record is found.